# C++ Mutex syntax and usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I have been doing a lot of research on Multi Threading Solutions using C++, but for some reason I have not been able to find any concrete syntax to using (while not using any libraries) I am rendering an image to the screen and separating screen space for each thread.

What I would like to happen is Have the thread increment a value and hang, once all threads have been through it will display it to the screen, and releasing the thread to start again.

```
void WaitForThreads(){
    WaitForSingleObject( hCompleteThread, INFINITE );
    IdleThreads++;
    if(IdleThreads==CoreMax){
        //Copy image to screen
        ReleaseMutex( hRelease);
    }
    ReleaseMutex( hCompleteThread);
    WaitForSingleObject( hRelease, INFINITE );
    IdleThreads--;
    if(IdleThreads>0){
        ReleaseMutex( hRelease);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am using the incorrect syntax or just not fully grasping what is going on.

Comment: You're using the Windows API – that's a library. If you're going to use a library anyway, why not use one that's cross-platform such as [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/)?

Comment: What behavior are you getting now with this code?

Comment: Or if you want to avoid using a library, write your own mutex in inline assembly.

Comment: I am not getting to the "IdleThreads--" 

Do you have any reference code/tutorial for writing it in assembly?/

Comment: Do you _really_ want to write it in assembly, given the high-quality, pre-tested, pre-documented C++ libraries out there?

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it is impossible to tell what you are up to. How are hCompleteThread and hRelease created? - that is, what are they?

Anyway, you can use a semaphore. Semaphores do the counting for you. They are a perfect match for this kind of producer/consumer stuff.